# scale a div after children or 100% of window height

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding `height: 100%`
how do you scale a div after the height of the window and at the same time after it's content
(So one overrides the other if it's not true)?

[standard height 100% css](https://jsfiddle.net/kjtetvg7/)
[How dose one scale the div after 100% or full height of it's content](https://jsfiddle.net/kjtetvg7/2/)

just ask and i will provide more info if something was unclear

Comment: after what? did you forget the words "is loaded", what about the window, what about its contents?

Comment: Use `min-height: 100%` on `fill` https://jsfiddle.net/kjtetvg7/3/

Comment: @NenadVracar 10/10 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Flexbox as I do in the snippet, but the key to viewport height and then expanding is `min-height: 100vh`; The `vh` property (short for viewport height) is pretty well-supported.

Please see the snippet for a demonstration.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.deck', function(evt) {
    
    $newEl = $('#copy-me').clone().text(HolderIpsum.words(~~(Math.random() * 20), true));

    $('.deck').append($newEl);
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
.deck {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.deck::after {
  content: 'CLICK ANYWHERE IN WHITE BOX TO ADD MORE CONTENT';
  order: 999;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: gray !important;
  border-color: gray !important;
}

.deck::after, .deck__card {
  flex: 33% 0 1;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background-color: blue;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 33vh;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/holder-ipsum/0.1/holder-ipsum.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deck">
  <div id="copy-me" class="deck__card" data-holder-ipsum-mode="words" data-holder-ipsum-words-count="3"></div>
</div>
```